# Methods for holonomic recurrences

Tags: differential-equations, recurrences, functional-equations

I wanted to ask if anyone knows of good texts/resources on methods for solving holonomic recurrence relations (if there are any general analytical approaches):
$$p_1(n)a(n)+p_2(n)a(n-1)+\dotsb+p_k(n)a(n-k+1) = 0,\quad \text{$p$ a polynomial in $n$}.$$

Only analytical approach I can find online is when we have a non-homogeneous two-term equation and can apply the method of summation factor.

Comment: A couple of such recurrences appear in Apery's celebrated proof (see [A proof that Euler missed](http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf) by Poorten), and their solutions don't have closed-form expressions but only representations as certain sums.